# How to get only the value of the first data object from a JSON response when there are more data objects with the same name?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api, url

I want a value from a JSON request to be filled in an source url as in the code I currently have below:

```
function Source() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "https://api.hitbox.tv/media/video/chairstream/list?filter=recent",
    success: function(data) {
        var idvid = data.media_id;
        document.getElementById("latest").src = "http://www.hitbox.tv/#!/embedvideo/" + idvid() + "?autoplay=true";
    }
});
```

Problem is that the variable `idvid` isn't doing his work in the url.
Another problem is that there are more data objects named `"media_id"` in the JSON response and I wan't to know how to get only the value of the first `media_id`. I'll be very happy when both problems could be solved.

Comment: Please post an example of the contents of the 'data' parameter value. First requirement without seeing anything else is: you need to parse 'data', which is a string, into a JSON object.

Comment: @DvS, jQuery automatically parses the data.

Comment: @Andy I'm not sure that you are right. I've just verified this in my own project and it is a string.

Comment: Then you did something wrong. [Re the dataType property](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): '"json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. Cross-domain "json" requests are converted to "jsonp" unless the request includes jsonp: false in its request options. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you have braces after `idvid` but it should just be

```
"http://www.hitbox.tv/#!/embedvideo/" + idvid + "?autoplay=true";
```

To get the `media_id` of the first object in the `data` array:

```
var idvid = data.video[0].media_id;
```

Comment: OP says "data objects". It's a fair assumption it's an array of objects that have the same format. OP needs the `media_id` from the first object in the array.

Comment: I upvoted you for having the smarts to actually check the JSON :)

Answer (score 2):

I called the URL and got it using this

```
data.video[0].media_id
```

so (dropping the () from the var too as suggested by Andy):

```
success: function(data) {
    $("#latest").attr("src","http://www.hitbox.tv/#!/embedvideo/" + 
     data.video[0].media_id + 
     "?autoplay=true");
}
```

```js
var data = {
  "request": {
    "this": "\/media\/video\/chairstream\/list"
  },
  "media_type": "video",
  "video": [{
    "media_user_name": "chairstream",
    "media_id": "783994",
    "media_file": "2c767c827c6c84a4714b9379983de69449c5a1c1-5658c80c2b938",
    "media_user_id": "871797",
    "media_profiles": "[{\"url\":\"\\\/chairstream\\\/2c767c827c6c84a4714b9379983de69449c5a1c1-5658c80c2b938\\\/chairstream\\\/index.m3u8\",\"height\":\"800\",\"bitrate\":0}]",
    "media_type_id": "2",
    "media_is_live": "1",
    "media_live_delay": "0",
    "media_date_added": "2015-11-27 23:16:04",
    "media_live_since": null,
    "media_transcoding": null,
    "media_chat_enabled": "1",
    "media_countries": null,
    "media_hosted_id": null,
    "media_mature": null,
    "media_hidden": null,
    "media_offline_id": null,
    "user_banned": null,
    "media_name": "2c767c827c6c84a4714b9379983de69449c5a1c1-5658c80c2b938",
    "media_display_name": "chairstream",
    "media_status": "Chairstream.com - Nov 27th #5",
    "media_title": "Chairstream.com - Nov 27th #5",
    "media_description": "",
    "media_description_md": null,
    "media_tags": "",
    "media_duration": "6262.0000",
    "media_bg_image": null,
    "media_views": "9",
    "media_views_daily": "2",
    "media_views_weekly": "9",
    "media_views_monthly": "9",
    "category_id": null,
    "category_name": null,
    "category_name_short": null,
    "category_seo_key": null,
    "category_viewers": null,
    "category_media_count": null,
    "category_channels": null,
    "category_logo_small": null,
    "category_logo_large": null,
    "category_updated": null,
    "team_name": null,
    "media_start_in_sec": "0",
    "media_duration_format": "01:44:22",
    "media_thumbnail": "\/static\/img\/media\/videos\/2c7\/2c767c827c6c84a4714b9379983de69449c5a1c1-5658c80c2b938_mid_000.jpg",
    "media_thumbnail_large": "\/static\/img\/media\/videos\/2c7\/2c767c827c6c84a4714b9379983de69449c5a1c1-5658c80c2b938_large_000.jpg",
    "channel": {
      "followers": "0",
      "user_id": "871797",
      "user_name": "chairstream",
      "user_status": "1",
      "user_logo": "\/static\/img\/channel\/chairstream_5602c1d59d02e_large.png",
      "user_cover": "\/static\/img\/channel\/cover_53e89056cf3ef.jpg",
      "user_logo_small": "\/static\/img\/channel\/chairstream_5602c1d59d02e_small.png",
      "user_partner": null,
      "partner_type": null,
      "user_beta_profile": "0",
      "media_is_live": "0",
      "media_live_since": "2015-11-30 12:35:33",
      "user_media_id": "206125",
      "twitter_account": null,
      "twitter_enabled": null,
      "livestream_count": "1"
    }
  }]
}

console.log(data.video[0].media_id)
```